# What are the names of all the ships?

Tags: monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge

In Monkey Island 2 there are several ships and shipwrecks. Captain Dread's boat, Captain Capsize's ship and the shipwreck come to my mind. Are there any more, and what are their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the ones I can remember:

- Captain Capsize's Glass-Bottomed Boat
- The Post Ship - you can fool people into thinking this ship arrives on Booty Island by using the horn purchased in the Booty Boutique (not sure you actually see this ship)
- The Mad Monkey - a sunken ship
- The Jolly Rasta (Dread's ship)
- The Limping Limpet was the ship that was used to find the Big Whoop (I don't think you see this boat)
- Woodtick on Scabb Island is a settlement made from ships

The books in the Phatt Island library probably refers to a lot more.

A list of ships across all Monkey Island titles can be found here (I am unsure if this list is complete):

[Monkey Island Wikia Ships Category Page](http://monkeyisland.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Ships)